# How to use hadoop fs -cp s3://<bucket> hdfs:///tmp

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I want to copy a file from s3 bucket to hdfs. I am abke to copy using the above command. But, how do I use this in java code to copy file from s3 to hdfs. I am able to implement filesystem.copyFromLocal and copytolocal but not -cp. How do i implemet this. Any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil which has all the file system commands. See here for example: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#line.285

You may also consider using s3distcp which is optimized for copying (and concatenating) files from S3 to HDFS and vice versa

Comment: Yes I have used hadoop-distcp-2.4.0.jar and it was solved. Thanks

Comment: Uugh, this is why you don't post link answers. They eventually die and the answer is useless.

Comment: @swdev I did specify you should look for org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil and added the link to the class docs... You can simply google org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil to get the latest docs.